# css border built of three image resources

Tags: html, css

I need to create a background border for a webpage. I have three image resources for this: left side, top, right side.

I'm having problem finding good css examples for this, only examples where only one image is used (border-image). Is it possible to do this with three images in a convenient way or do I need to build up the webpage with divs that surround the webpage?

I have tried to find information about this without any success and I get a warning about my question being to general. So maybe I'm not aware of the term being used to describe this technique?

Comment: Could you please provide your current html and css or a jsfiddle so we can see the issue.

Comment: You either want a background image (or multiple), or a border. A “background border” isn’t really a thing. Please be a bit more descriptive in what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try someting like :

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  position: relative;
  background: url(center.png);
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
div:before, div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
div:before {
  left:0;
  background: url(left.png);
}
div:after {
  right:0;
  background: url(right.png);
}
```